# functions in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

How to write functions in angular 2.

This is the sample login form. But I can't able to write functions in angular 2 . How to write nested functions in angular 2. I don't want to conver this entire code in angular 2. Please give me the suggestion how can I convert this code in angular 2.

```js
$scope.submitloginForm = function(formValid, username, password) {
        $scope.loginSubmitted = true;

        function getFirstItem() {
            return $http({
                method: 'post',
                url: $rootScope.URL + "/api/login",
                data: { "username": username, "password": password }
            });
        }

        function getDependantItem() {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: $rootScope.URL + "/api/getConfigurationWeb?access_token=" + $rootScope.accessToken
            });
        }

   if (formValid) {
            $scope.loading = true;
            getFirstItem().then(function(result1) {
                console.log(result1.data);
                sessionStorage.Token = result1.data.id;
                $rootScope.accessToken = sessionStorage.Token;

                getDependantItem().then(function(result2) {
                    $rootScope.configuration = result2.data.data;

                    $sessionStorage.configData = result2;
                   
                    
                }, function(error2) {
                    
                });
            }, function(error1) {
                
            }).finally(function() {
                
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't mean to be condescending but google wrote a pretty neat step-by-step documentation to start with Angular. You should read that instead of asking SO community. https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: i think this is angularjs not Angular2

Comment: this is angularjs 1x code you need to rewrite the whole code using angular2 ..

Comment: Even there is an `ngUpgrade` library provided by angular to upgrade your angularjs code to angular 2 https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Comment: i know this is angular 1.x. Please read my question. I asked only how to write nested functions in angular 2. I show angularjs code just for example.

Answer (score 0):

From angular.io

The ngUpgrade library in Angular is a very useful tool for upgrading anything but the smallest of applications. With it you can mix and match AngularJS and Angular components in the same application and have them interoperate seamlessly. That means you don't have to do the upgrade work all at once, since there's a natural coexistence between the two frameworks during the transition period.